# Element-wise operation on tensorflow tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow, and need to do something that in any other context wouldn't be that hard.

I need to take a tensor with shape (?, 224, 224, 3) and apply an operation to each element, leaving the size in tact. I've tried tf.map_fn(myFunc, data), but it seems like what gets passed in to myFunc is a subset of the original tensor.

Is there any easy way to just say "do this operation to everything in the tensor"?

Comment: I think it depends on what is inside myFunc

Comment: An arbitrarily complicated operation, going from a float to another float.

Comment: You could try using the tf.py_func operator as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is [broad casting semantics](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to vectorize your input, apply the function, then unvectorize. Something like this

```
y_shape = tf.shape( y )
y_vec = tf.reshape( y, [-1] )
fy_vec = tf.map_fn( fn, y_vec )
fy = tf.reshape( fy_vec, y_shape )
```

This would work as long as your function maps scalars to scalars.